# Load a partial from an action into an Iframe

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-4, internet-explorer, iframe

I am having some performance issues in IE when a very large amount of HTML is returned as a partial view from an AjAX call to an Action and is then inserted into the DOM. In Some cases the resulting view is a 26 MB table and IE runs into critical memory issues when attempting to insert this into the DOM.

Id like to be able instead just have the partial load into an Iframe so there is no DOM insertion needed but I'm not sure how to do this. The Action expects a fairly complex JSON object to be able top construct the resulting View.

Ultimately I want to set the target of an Iframe to an action that returns a View and be able to still pass the action the necessary JSON object it needs to render the view. This way the view is simply loaded rather than relying on IE's dodgy DOM manipulation to insert the data.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

First, by removing the AJAX requirement, you're also removing the need to work with JSON. JSON is still going to require JavaScript to process in the view, and JavaScript being responsible for parsing and manipulating a 26MB JSON object is always going to be a problem.

If you're okay with moving to an iframe, you can then pass an actual strongly-typed model to your view, and then let Razor do the heavy-lifting of generating HTML based on the model. For this, you don't want to use a partial view, but rather a view with no layout. Simply add the following to the top of the cshtml:

```
@{ Layout = null; }
```

Then, you just handle the whole thing like any other action that returns a view in MVC.

Comment: I am already letting Razor dot he work, my action is returning a partial back via AJAX, so the 26MB is actually the markup of that partial. The AJAX call is made upon a button click with a JSON object being passed to the action to generate the view. What I want to do instead is on the button click have the JSON object be used to load a View as the target for an IFrame.